# Making a callout To Marketing cloud from Service Cloud External Services

Tags: marketing-cloud, visual-flows, namedcredentials, external-services

I have been trying to invoke Marketing Cloud Transactional API from Salesforce Service cloud. I saw there is a Marketing Cloud Open API Spec for Transactional Messaging: **https://sforce.co/2GuuYMn** and I decided to make a connection through flows and External Services.I was able to create External services through it but I am not sure how to make a authentication call to SFMC first from Lightning Flows so that I get a token and then invoke the endpoints from transactional API.Is it possible to achieve it or am i asking for too much from Flows??

Comment: Please refer this [Transactional API](https://www.salesforcefan.com/post/trigger-transactional-messaging-email-from-cloudpage-using-ssjs) excellent blog by [Naveen VM](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/48928/naveen-vm?tab=profile)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding how to authenticate with SFMC, here is what you need:

- Within SFMC: Go into Administration > Installed Packages and find/create the installed package (server-to-server type) you are using to authenticate and make REST calls. More info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm).
- Next step is to define/check the API Integration Permission Scopes for your installed package. More info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/data-access-permissions.htm).

To use the transactional API you will need below scopes defined:

-- Email - Read, Write, Send

-- Lists and Subscribers - Read, Write

-- Data Extensions - Read, Write

-- Interactions - Read, Write, Execute

- Once you've setup the package you'll be able to retrieve ClientId, ClientSecret and Authentication URI. More info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm).
- Below is a sample payload from the official SF documentation:

> ```
> Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.auth.marketingcloudapis.com
> POST /v2/token
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> {
> "grant_type": "client_credentials",
> "client_id": "7a9j47upktedde30uedl822p",
> "client_secret": "1955278925675241571",
> "scope": "email_read email_write email_send",
> "account_id": "12345"
> }
> ```

- With regards to flow setup I am not sure what is involved but if you could manage to setup transactional API requests then this one shouldn't be vastly different.

Comment: Sapoka,The problem is not setting it up in Marketing Cloud and installed packages and configurations.I am trying to connect to Marketing cloud from Service cloud through Flows/External Services.

Comment: @Chetan your post says "but I am not sure how to make a authentication call to SFMC first so that I get a token and then invoke the endpoints from transactional API." So I have provided on steps to authenticate with SFMC. Now if your question was regarding on how to setup in FLOW, you should post this question in SFDC for better success. Hope this helps